# OpenLayers3 Navigation control

Tags: maps, openlayers, navigation

I want to navigate the map using mouse drag. we did it in openlayers2 using navigator control. Does Openlayers 3 have navigation control? should I add it to map like Openlayers 2?

Comment: Have you looked at the OpenLayers 3 examples? In particular, http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/drag-rotate-and-zoom.html

Comment: Yes I did, I use the same structure but I cannot drag the map. Maybe i forget to set anything, for that I need to know what control is responsible for map navigatition

Comment: It works in the example, and you have the source code for that example linked off the example page at http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/drag-rotate-and-zoom.js. Perhaps you need to post a small, self-contained example showing what you are doing?

Comment: I found the problem, I added ol.interaction.Select({condition:ol.events.condition.mouseMove}) which prevents map dragging

Comment: this example http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/vector-layer.html solves navigation issue with mouse over interaction

Comment: Some people tend to avoid reading comments when searching for solutions so could you post your comments as an answer please (and accept it after 2 days)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, I added `ol.interaction.Select({condition:ol.events.condition.mouseMove})` which prevents map dragging.

The [vector-layer.html](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/vector-layer.html) example solves navigation issue with mouseover interaction